# ngFor slow in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular7

Following component take up to 3 seconds to render in IE on powerful laptop, while it is fast in Edge or Chrome.

```
<div *ngFor="let clock of clocks">
  <select>
    <option *ngFor="let zone of zones">{{zone}}</option>
  </select>
</div>


clocks = [0,2,3,4]
zones: string[] = moment.tz.names(); // cca 500 items
```

Why it is significantly slower in IE than other browsers and how to make it faster?

Maybe it's worth mentioning that I'm using core-js and the component is displayed in modal dialog

Comment: You could try to [track your items](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation) to improve performance.

Comment: This should help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8112

Comment: How do you get the names, using the service? Try to use [F12 developer tools Network tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004%28v%3dvs.85%29) to check the spend time when loading the resource.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the performance issue with IE11, I used core-js instead of es6-shims.
Steps are (may differ depending on your build process):

`1.npm i core-js --save
 2.replace references to node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shims.min.js with 
 node_modules/core-js/client/core.min.js`.

So far, it seems to be working fine and performance is much closer to Chrome.
I haven't had time to fully test and that may cause other issues.